# Is there a closed form, or a series approximation, for $ f(x)=\int_{1}^{x} \left(\cos\left( \frac{\pi r}{t}\right)+\cos(\pi t)\right)^{N}dt $?

Tags: integration, periodic-functions

How can I solve this integral, that is find f(x)?
$$
f(x)=\int_{1}^{x} \left(\cos\left( \frac{\pi r}{t}\right)+\cos(\pi t)\right)^{N}dt
$$
Could it be possible to obtain a closed form of $f(x)$?
Alternatively, could it be possible to find an approximation of this integral using the Taylor series expansion of the integrand and integrate it piece-wise?

Having
$$
g(t)=\left(\cos\left( \frac{\pi r}{t}\right)+cos(\pi t)\right)^{N}
$$
the Taylor series is

$$
g(t) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{g^{(n)}(a)}{n!} (t-a)^n
$$

Can I compute the derivatives value up to a certain degree $M$, and use the integral of  nth-power in order to estimate this integral?

That is the indefinite integral should be something like:
$$
\int g(t) dt = C+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{g^{(n)}(a)}{n!} \frac{(t-a)^{n+1}}{n+1}
$$

Does it converge? Can I go by this way?
Others integration methods are error prones.
Is it possible to evaluate it at arbitrary precision?

Comment: The dummy index of integral has appeared as such in bounds.

Comment: Don't use $x$ as an external constant and a variable of integration. Write: $$\int_1^x f(t)\,dt$$ Do not write: $$\int_1^x f(x)\,dx$$

Comment: That said, it seems unlikely you can get a closed form, but that is just a guess.

Comment: Typo. Thanks. Fixed the index :)

Comment: What about to express it as a Taylor series and then apply the integrals on each term?

Comment: Maybe you can use binomial theorem

Comment: Could you address me in that?

Comment: @alexroat it was just a suggestion, I don't think it'll work. Try to expand the argument using binomial theorem and you may obtain a reduction formula